# Failed to activate devenv-3.8-c in setting up development env

Tags: windows, git, github, conda, development-environment

ERROR Command :- C:\Users\WIN10\conda>`.\dev\start`

```
Downloading miniconda...
Installing development environment...
Creating devenv-3.8-c...
Updating devenv-3.8-c...
Initializing shell integration...
menuinst called from non-root env C:\Users\WIN10\conda\devenv\Windows\envs\devenv-3.8-c
rm -rf C:\Users\WIN10\conda\devenv\Windows\envs\devenv-3.8-c\Lib\site-packages\conda-23.1.0-py3.8.egg-info
rm -rf C:\Users\WIN10\conda\devenv\Windows\envs\devenv-3.8-c\Lib\site-packages\conda
rm -rf C:\Users\WIN10\conda\devenv\Windows\envs\devenv-3.8-c\Lib\site-packages\conda_env
Activating devenv-3.8-c...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WIN10\conda\devenv\Windows\envs\devenv-3.8-c\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
  File "C:\Users\WIN10\conda\conda\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .deprecations import deprecated
  File "C:\Users\WIN10\conda\conda\deprecations.py", line 266, in <module>
    deprecated = DeprecationHandler(__version__)
  File "C:\Users\WIN10\conda\conda\deprecations.py", line 29, in __init__
    self._version = parse(version)
  File "C:\Users\WIN10\conda\devenv\Windows\envs\devenv-3.8-c\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 52, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "C:\Users\WIN10\conda\devenv\Windows\envs\devenv-3.8-c\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 195, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-li

ke object
Error: failed to activate devenv-3.8-c
```

If you have any suggestion do let me know as soon as possible!

I am trying to set up development env for conda.

My Reference :- [Development Environment, Windows cmd.exe shell](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/contributing.html#development-environment-windows-cmd-exe-shell)

did everything as specified git is set to path ..etc

Ran the following command

`set GITHUB_USERNAME=pravincoder`

`git clone https://github.com/pravincoder/conda.git "%CONDA_PROJECT_ROOT%"`

`cd "%CONDA_PROJECT_ROOT%"`

`git remote add %GITHUB_USERNAME% https://github.com/pravincoder/conda.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda maintainer here. This is more appropriate to report as an issue to the conda project itself:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/new/choose